# How to multiple across columns in dataset and save to new dataset without changing original data in R

Tags: r

I want to multiply all the values in columns e.g. by 5, and then save the results into a new dataset, without changing the data being read in.

Using a loop I use the following R code:

> raw_data[,i]<-raw_data[,i]*5

What I want is to keep the original data as it is, raw_data, and save the multiplied data into e.g. new_data:

> new_data[,i]<-raw_data[,i]*5

I get an error saying the object 'new_data' is not found.

Is there a neat way of doing this, or do you have to create the new_data object first as an empty dataset?

Answer (score 1):

No need for loops here.

```
# a toy data frame
raw_data <- data.frame(x = 1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6)
# same applies if you have your data in a matrix
# raw_data <- matrix(1:6, ncol = 3)
raw_data
#   x y z
# 1 1 3 5
# 2 2 4 6

new_data <- raw_data * 5
new_data
#    x  y  z
# 1  5 15 25
# 2 10 20 30
```

Comment: That is an easier method, thank you. I have an example of what I am trying to do: > raw_data <- data.frame(s = c("aa", "bb"), x = 1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6) ;   > new_data <- raw_data[2:3] * 5 ; This multiplies all the numeric columns, but then I lose the character column. The multiplication does not work on the character column, is there a way to keep the character column?